# IOException with URLConnection and getInputStream

Tags: java, android, inputstream, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to get data from a website with an android application.

Here is my code :

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=Schriesheim,Germany");
URLConnection uCon = url.openConnection();
iStream = uCon.getInputStream();
```

The method getInputStream() returns me an IOException, I already tried lots of things find on Internet, but nothing is working.
By the way, I tried this code in a Java application and it worked so I assume this the problem is in my Android settings.

I already add these lines in my Manifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I'm using Eclipse and running Archlinux x64.
Any idea ?

Thank you.

Comment: any solution for this one worked for you?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this function for get data from internet

```
        public static String get(String from) {
            try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
                HttpGet get = new HttpGet(from);
                HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);  
                HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();  
                if (resEntityGet != null) return EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("GET", e.toString());
                }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for you help. But I get an IO Exception with this :

`responseGet = client.execute(get); `

I really think this is an android configuration issue, but I can't figure it out..

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
uCon.setDoInput(true);
```

before

```
uCon.getInputStream();
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem, copied all the code to a new project and it helped, the old one did not work. I think it's a curse or demon powers guys