# Android - .getInputStream() keeps on crashing

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm really new to Android, java and HTML. So I'm pretty much stuffed.
I'm just trying to get data from a URL with an android application.
I tried the following code in java and it works fine, so I really stuck with what is wrong with it.
I tried googling and used different options, such as setting connection time

```
    URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    try {
        input = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
        in =new BufferedReader(input);
    }
```

I tried a lot of different versions, such as adding a bunch of stuff like:
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("ConnectionTimeout", "12000");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + request.length);

I think the following post has a similar problem:
[IOException with URLConnection and getInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057942/ioexception-with-urlconnection-and-getinputstream/17413587#17413587)

I didn't get an IOException (well at least I don't think so), but I got this (and a whole bunch of others)

07-01 23:18:33.870: E/AndroidRuntime(30713): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

And yes, I did add the permission to INTERNET and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

I'm using Eclipse and running on my Android HTC One X.
Please help. Thanks in advance!

Here's the stack trace after I added the AsyncTask:

```
07-02 00:02:34.775: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3799): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:02:34.785: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3799): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:02:34.785: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3799): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:02:34.785: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3799): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:02:34.790: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3799): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:02:34.795: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3799): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:02:34.795: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3799): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:02:34.795: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3799): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:02:34.800: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3799): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:02:34.800: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3799): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:02:34.800: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3799): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:02:34.805: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3799): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:02:34.805: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3799): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:02:34.810: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3799): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:02:34.810: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3799): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:02:34.815: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3799): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:02:34.815: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3799): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:02:34.820: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3799): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:02:34.820: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3799): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:02:34.830: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3799): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:02:34.830: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3799): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:02:34.830: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3799): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:02:34.835: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3799): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:02:34.845: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3799): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:02:34.845: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3799): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:02:34.845: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3799): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:02:34.850: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3799): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:02:34.850: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3799): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:02:34.855: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3799): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:02:34.855: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3799): setComposingRegion on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:02:34.855: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3799): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:02:34.865: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3799): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:02:34.865: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3799): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:02:34.870: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3799): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:02:34.870: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3799): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:06.105: W/LoadedApk(5867): pakageInfo is null! try again
07-02 00:05:06.105: W/LoadedApk(5867): packageInfo still null!
07-02 00:05:06.110: D/LoadedApk(5867): dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
07-02 00:05:06.110: D/LoadedApk(5867): java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:599)
07-02 00:05:06.110: D/LoadedApk(5867): android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:388)
07-02 00:05:06.110: D/LoadedApk(5867): android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:330)
07-02 00:05:06.110: D/LoadedApk(5867): android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:535)
07-02 00:05:06.110: D/LoadedApk(5867): android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4803)
07-02 00:05:06.110: D/LoadedApk(5867): android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151)
07-02 00:05:06.110: D/LoadedApk(5867): android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1401)
07-02 00:05:06.110: D/LoadedApk(5867): android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-02 00:05:06.110: D/LoadedApk(5867): android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
07-02 00:05:06.110: D/LoadedApk(5867): android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
07-02 00:05:06.110: D/LoadedApk(5867): java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-02 00:05:06.110: D/LoadedApk(5867): java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-02 00:05:06.110: D/LoadedApk(5867): com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
07-02 00:05:06.110: D/LoadedApk(5867): com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:795)
07-02 00:05:06.110: D/LoadedApk(5867): dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-02 00:05:09.565: I/dalvikvm-heap(6053): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.448MB for 1705652-byte allocation
07-02 00:05:09.810: I/dalvikvm-heap(6053): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.340MB for 3034580-byte allocation
07-02 00:05:09.905: I/MediaPlayer(6053): setLPAflag() in
07-02 00:05:09.905: I/MediaPlayer(6053): mContext is null, can't getMirrorDisplayStatus!!!
07-02 00:05:09.905: I/MediaPlayer(6053): setLPAflag() out
07-02 00:05:09.910: W/MediaPlayer(6053): info/warning (1, 902)
07-02 00:05:09.915: D/MediaPlayer(6053): [DLNA]contentType = 902
07-02 00:05:09.915: D/MediaPlayer(6053): doStart() in
07-02 00:05:09.915: D/MediaPlayer(6053): getIntParameter = 902
07-02 00:05:10.190: D/MediaPlayer(6053): Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 200
07-02 00:05:10.190: I/MediaPlayer(6053): Info (1,902)
07-02 00:05:10.190: D/MediaPlayer(6053): Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 5
07-02 00:05:10.190: D/MediaPlayer(6053): Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 1
07-02 00:05:10.295: E/(6053): file /data/data/com.nvidia.NvCPLSvc/files/driverlist.txt: not found!
07-02 00:05:10.295: I/(6053): Attempting to load EGL implementation /system/lib//egl/libEGL_tegra_impl
07-02 00:05:10.485: I/(6053): Loaded EGL implementation /system/lib//egl/libEGL_tegra_impl
07-02 00:05:10.595: I/(6053): Loading GLESv2 implementation /system/lib//egl/libGLESv2_tegra_impl
07-02 00:05:11.080: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:11.140: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:11.430: I/dalvikvm-heap(6053): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.851MB for 2731536-byte allocation
07-02 00:05:11.830: I/MediaPlayer(6053): setLPAflag() in
07-02 00:05:11.830: I/MediaPlayer(6053): mContext is null, can't getMirrorDisplayStatus!!!
07-02 00:05:11.830: I/MediaPlayer(6053): setLPAflag() out
07-02 00:05:11.845: W/MediaPlayer(6053): info/warning (1, 902)
07-02 00:05:11.870: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:11.875: D/MediaPlayer(6053): Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 200
07-02 00:05:11.875: I/MediaPlayer(6053): Info (1,902)
07-02 00:05:11.875: D/MediaPlayer(6053): Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 5
07-02 00:05:11.875: D/MediaPlayer(6053): Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 1
07-02 00:05:12.025: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:12.600: D/MediaPlayer(6053): [DLNA]contentType = 902
07-02 00:05:12.600: D/MediaPlayer(6053): doStart() in
07-02 00:05:12.600: D/MediaPlayer(6053): getIntParameter = 902
07-02 00:05:12.645: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:12.940: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:12.945: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:12.950: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:12.955: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:12.960: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:12.965: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:12.980: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:12.980: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:12.985: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:12.985: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:12.995: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:13.000: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:13.000: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:13.005: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:13.005: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:13.010: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:13.010: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:13.010: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:13.015: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:13.015: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:13.015: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:13.015: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:13.015: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:13.020: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:13.020: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:13.020: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:13.020: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:13.020: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:13.025: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:13.025: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): setComposingRegion on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:13.025: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:13.025: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:13.025: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:13.025: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:13.025: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(6053): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
07-02 00:05:13.165: E/SpannableStringBuilder(6053): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
07-02 00:05:13.165: E/SpannableStringBuilder(6053): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
07-02 00:05:13.295: D/MediaPlayer(6053): Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 2
07-02 00:05:16.440: W/System.err(6053): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.google.com/
07-02 00:05:16.445: W/System.err(6053):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
07-02 00:05:16.445: W/System.err(6053):     at aiti.mit.edu.sa.wu.calculator.MyAsynTask.doInBackground(ActivityHi.java:139)
07-02 00:05:16.445: W/System.err(6053):     at aiti.mit.edu.sa.wu.calculator.MyAsynTask.doInBackground(ActivityHi.java:1)
07-02 00:05:16.445: W/System.err(6053):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-02 00:05:16.445: W/System.err(6053):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-02 00:05:16.445: W/System.err(6053):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-02 00:05:16.445: W/System.err(6053):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
07-02 00:05:16.445: W/System.err(6053):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-02 00:05:16.450: W/System.err(6053):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-02 00:05:16.450: W/System.err(6053):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
07-02 00:05:16.450: W/dalvikvm(6053): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c392d0)
07-02 00:05:16.460: E/AndroidRuntime(6053): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
07-02 00:05:16.460: E/AndroidRuntime(6053): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-02 00:05:16.460: E/AndroidRuntime(6053):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
07-02 00:05:16.460: E/AndroidRuntime(6053):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
07-02 00:05:16.460: E/AndroidRuntime(6053):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
07-02 00:05:16.460: E/AndroidRuntime(6053):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
07-02 00:05:16.460: E/AndroidRuntime(6053):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-02 00:05:16.460: E/AndroidRuntime(6053):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
07-02 00:05:16.460: E/AndroidRuntime(6053):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-02 00:05:16.460: E/AndroidRuntime(6053):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-02 00:05:16.460: E/AndroidRuntime(6053):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
07-02 00:05:16.460: E/AndroidRuntime(6053): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-02 00:05:16.460: E/AndroidRuntime(6053):     at aiti.mit.edu.sa.wu.calculator.MyAsynTask.doInBackground(ActivityHi.java:153)
07-02 00:05:16.460: E/AndroidRuntime(6053):     at aiti.mit.edu.sa.wu.calculator.MyAsynTask.doInBackground(ActivityHi.java:1)
07-02 00:05:16.460: E/AndroidRuntime(6053):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-02 00:05:16.460: E/AndroidRuntime(6053):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-02 00:05:16.460: E/AndroidRuntime(6053):     ... 5 more
07-02 00:05:19.770: D/Process(6053): killProcess, pid=6053
07-02 00:05:19.800: D/Process(6053): dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
07-02 00:05:19.800: D/Process(6053): java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:599)
07-02 00:05:19.800: D/Process(6053): android.os.Process.killProcess(Process.java:944)
07-02 00:05:19.800: D/Process(6053): com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:108)
07-02 00:05:19.800: D/Process(6053): java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
07-02 00:05:19.800: D/Process(6053): java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
07-02 00:05:20.290: I/dalvikvm-heap(6336): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.287MB for 1536016-byte allocation
07-02 00:05:20.375: I/dalvikvm-heap(6336): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.890MB for 2731536-byte allocation
07-02 00:05:20.590: I/MediaPlayer(6336): setLPAflag() in
07-02 00:05:20.590: I/MediaPlayer(6336): mContext is null, can't getMirrorDisplayStatus!!!
07-02 00:05:20.590: I/MediaPlayer(6336): setLPAflag() out
07-02 00:05:20.590: W/MediaPlayer(6336): info/warning (1, 902)
07-02 00:05:20.635: D/MediaPlayer(6336): Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 200
07-02 00:05:20.635: I/MediaPlayer(6336): Info (1,902)
07-02 00:05:20.635: D/MediaPlayer(6336): Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 5
07-02 00:05:20.635: D/MediaPlayer(6336): Mediaplayer receives message, message type: 1
07-02 00:05:20.685: E/(6336): file /data/data/com.nvidia.NvCPLSvc/files/driverlist.txt: not found!
07-02 00:05:20.685: I/(6336): Attempting to load EGL implementation /system/lib//egl/libEGL_tegra_impl
07-02 00:05:20.735: I/(6336): Loaded EGL implementation /system/lib//egl/libEGL_tegra_impl
07-02 00:05:20.820: I/(6336): Loading GLESv2 implementation /system/lib//egl/libGLESv2_tegra_impl
07-02 00:05:21.215: E/SpannableStringBuilder(6336): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
07-02 00:05:21.215: E/SpannableStringBuilder(6336): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
07-02 00:05:22.575: E/SpannableStringBuilder(6336): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
07-02 00:05:22.575: E/SpannableStringBuilder(6336): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
```

and this is AsyncTank...

```
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        input = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
        in =new BufferedReader(input);
        System.out.println("HELLO");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        conn.disconnect();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Paste the full stack trace as an edit to your question.

Comment: Without posting the stack trace, no one can do anything but guess.

Comment: What's on ActivityHi.java line 153?

Comment: line153 conn.disconnect();

Comment: Oh gee. If I comment that out then it totally doesn't break. I think that's a good thing, thanks!!!!!

Comment: @manyobject No the root cause is variable scoping - adding an `if` will just hide the problem.  I've added an answer.  @Mel is calling disconnect on the wrong `conn`.

Comment: Ah well spotted @Martin. Also, my comment should have said if(conn != null) too. I still think this check should still be done before disconnect(), but really the issue is the duplicate conn variables. Bottom line, if you open a connection; close it.

Comment: Thank you guys so much! I'll remember to close all connections in the future!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That AsyncTask you posted makes the problem obvious. Commenting out 153 is just hiding the bug.

You're declaring and assigning `conn` inside the try block (`HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();`), and disconnecting in your `finally`.

But that `conn` you've connected to is not visible from the finally block.  That means you probably have a member variable with the same name.  You're trying to disconnect that instead.

You're getting a *NullPointerException* because the member is *null*.

To start with, I'd suggest changing `conn` to something else like `conn2` to make the problem more obvious (you'll get a compile error on line 153).

The correct solution is to move the declaration and assignment of `conn` outside the try block so that it is visible to the finally block, and rejig your catch blocks as appropriate.  Something like (I haven't tested this):

```
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        try {
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            input = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
            in =new BufferedReader(input);
            System.out.println("HELLO");
        }
        finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I had to add a } before finally to get it to run, but this totally works!
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are trying to do this on the Main UI Thread, you can't do this on ICS or Jellybean, you need to do this inside an [**AsyncTask**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), and that way you should be fine.

Comment: If you are referring to StrictMode - it would throw a android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException, rather than a FileNotFoundException.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that if you take a look [at the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) back at developer.android.com you'd get your code to work.

Their sample looks like this:

```
   URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/");
   HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   try {
     InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
     readStream(in);
    finally {
     urlConnection.disconnect();
   }
```

It's similar to yours, but the log you posted is complaining that

```
07-02 00:05:16.440: W/System.err(6053): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.google.com/
```

which leads to this null pointer exception

```
07-02 00:05:16.460: E/AndroidRuntime(6053): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

which I guess is on this line

```
 conn.setDoInput(true);
```

Comment: I tried to comment out that line but it doesn't help even after I added a readStream() method. My brain is too stuffed right now, will come back to it tomorrow morning. Thanks for the help, really appreciated!

Comment: Oh in any case, it seems like I still got the data! Is it really necessary to add .disconnect()?

Comment: Yes. Just check if it is null before calling disconnect (see my comment response to your question).

Comment: Yes, you must call disconnect (otherwise you're going to start leaking resources).  Don't put in the test for null though - it will result in you never calling disconnect in your case (or calling it on the wrong connection).  See my answer for details.